# Follow redirect URL in jquery get() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I was sending a get request to google app script url in my application using Jquery's get method. it was working fine but suddenly that api has started to redirect to some other url in case of authentication error. so i am getting an empty string with 302 status code.
So is there any way i can follow the redirected URL using jquery get method or any other way?

here is how i am calling that google app script url

```
$.get(url).done(function( data ){
    console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `fetch` with `{ redirect: 'follow'}` option turned on ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Supplying_request_options))

It might look something like this:

```
fetch(url,{ redirect: 'follow' })
  .then(data => console.log(data)); 
}
```